# Calculate a score from an existing fields with conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm working on MongoDB 2.6.9 and NodeJs 0.10.37 and I have a collection `vols` which means flights.

```
> db.vols.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5717a5d4578f3f2556f300f2"),
    "Orig" : "AGP",
    "Dest" : "OTP",
    "Flight" : 126,
    "Routing" : "AGP-OTP",
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 169,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-14",
    "Mkt_Al" : "0B",
    "Dep_Time" : 1110,
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Arr_Time" : 1600,
    "Block_Mins" : 230

}
```

Each document refers to one flight done by an Airline Company and it gives details, for instance, the previous document refers to a flight done directly ( Stops : 0 ). But the next one, the flight was with stop.

```
db.vols.findOne({Stops:1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5717a5d4578f3f2556f301c5"),
    "Orig" : "CEK",
    "Dest" : "IKT",
    "Flight" : 7756,
    "Routing" : "KZN-CEK-OVB-IKT",
    "Stops" : 1,
    "Seats" : 70,
    "Ops_Week" : 2,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-11",
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Dep_Time" : 1655,
    "Thru_Point" : "OVB",
    "Arr_Time" : 140,
    "Block_Mins" : 345
}
```

**Important:**

Each `Airline` has a `score` in every route ( `Origin` - `Destination` )

**How to calculate the score ?**

[image]

So, I need to do these calculations and insert a new Field " QSI " into my collection `vols`.

**Important :**

Average elapsed time in `c4` means this :

For example we have a flight with stop let's say : a flight from **A** to **C** by **B**, the whole flight makes for example 60 min, but from **A** to **B** makes 20 min and from **B** to **C** makes 20 min, this average should return 40 min.

I tried this Solution, but for `c4` things don't look like smething work :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express  = require('express'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ramtest');

var volsSchema = new Schema({}, { strict : false, collection : 'vols' });
var MyModel    = mongoose.model("MyModel", volsSchema);

mongoose.set('debug', true);

mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var bulkUpdateOps = MyModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
      counter       = 0;

  MyModel.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;

    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
      // computations
      var c1, c2, c3, c4, qsi, first_leg, second_leg, total_flight;

      c1 = 0.3728 + (0.00454 * doc.Seats);
      c2 = (doc.Stops == 1) ? 0.03 : 1;
      c3 = doc.Ops_Week;

      if (doc.Stops == 1) {
        var Mkt_Air        = doc.Mkt_Al,
            Origin         = doc.Orig,
            Destination    = doc.Dest,
            Thru_Point     = doc.Thru_Point,
            Effective_Date = doc.Eff_Date,
            Block_Mins     = doc.Block_Mins;

        MyModel.find({ Mkt_Al : Mkt_Air }, { Orig : Origin }, { Dest : Thru_Point }, { Eff_Date : Effective_Date }).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
          docs.forEach(function(doc) {
            var first_leg = doc.Block_Mins;
            MyModel.find({ Mkt_Al : Mkt_Air }, { Orig : Thru_Point }, { Dest : Destination }, { Eff_Date : Effective_Date }).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
              docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                var second_leg = doc.Block_Mins, total_flight = second_leg + first_leg;
                c4 = Math.pow((Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);
                qsi = c1 * c2 * c3 * c4;
              }); // the end of docs.forEach(function (doc){
            }); // the end of MyModel.find..
          }); // the end of docs.forEach(function (doc){
        }); // the end of MyModel.find..
      } // end if
      else {
        c4 = 1;
      }

      qsi = c1 * c2 * c3 * c4;

      counter++;

      bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set" : { "Qsi" : qsi }
      });

      if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          bulkUpdateOps = MyModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
          console.log(result);
          console.log(doc);
        });
      }

    });

    if (counter % 500 != 0) {
      bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    }
  });

  var app = express();
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Ready to calculate and insert the QSI');
  });
});
```

**The problem:**

I think that the problem is with `MyModel.find` like if i lose data inside this instruction ..., my `score` is calculated cleanly when `Stops = 0`, but if `Stops = 1`, My score takes the value `Nan`, and I have an error after some iterations like that `callback(null, docs)` please who can help ??

How can I achieve the above ?

Comment: Can you please improve the formatting. It's hard to follow the indentation.

Comment: I tried to make it too clear now ...

Comment: @JeanDupont I took the liberty to properly reformat it for you.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you much much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your implementation. Firstly, you are using the **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** method incorrectly as you are specifying too many arguments for the query:

```
MyModel.find(
    { Mkt_Al : Mkt_Air }, 
    { Orig : Origin }, 
    { Dest : Thru_Point }, 
    { Eff_Date : Effective_Date }
).lean().exec(function(err, docs) { .. }
```

should be

```
MyModel.find({ 
    Mkt_Al: Mkt_Air, 
    Orig: Origin, 
    Dest: Thru_Point, 
    Eff_Date: Effective_Date 
}).lean().exec(function(err, docs) { ... }
```

---

Again, you shouldn't be using the **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** method in this instance because you only need a single document that matches the query to use in your computations. Taking the complex algorithm from your previous closed question:

> Now I want to calculate a score **`c4`** and insert it into my collection :
>
> To do that I should calculate a value **`c4`** just like this :
>
> 1) First I verify for each document if **`( Field2 == 1 )`** if it's true I
>   continue else it's simple **`c4`** takes value 1.
>
> 2) Then I should make a loop "for" and see which document verify these
>   conditions : **`doc.Field1 == this.Field1 && doc.Field6 == this.Field6 &&
>   doc.Field7 == this.Field8`**
>
> 3) Then I take **`doc.Field4`** wich will be added to another document's
>   **`Field4`**
>
> 4) I continue and I make another loop and look for another document
>   wich verify these conditions :
>
> it should have the same **`Field1`** just like the previous document and its
>   **`Field6`** equal to the previous document **`Field7`** and its **`Field8`** the same
>   as Field8 in the first document
>
> 5) Then I take **`doc.Field4`** and add it to the previous **`doc.Field4`**

Using `MyModel.findOne()` should suffice for tasks 3, 4 and 5 above. However, because of the asynchronous nature of the calls, you would need to nest the queries but fortunately the depth of the nested calls is not greater than 3 otherwise you will find yourself with a one-way ticket to Callback Hell. To avoid these common pitfalls, better to use **[`Promises`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)** (since the native mongoose queries by default can return a **[`Promise`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise)**) or use the **[`node-async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)** package which includes a number of functions for dealing with situations like this.

If using the **[`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)** library, it efficiently allows you to run run multiple asynchronous tasks (like the `MyModel.findOne()` calls) that depend on each other and when they all finish do something else. In the above, you could use the **[`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** method.

---

The following example demonstrates the above concept where you can calculate the **`Qsi`** from the following sample documents in the test db.

**Populate test db's vol collection:**

```
db.vols.insert([
    {    
        "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
        "Stops" : 0,
        "Seats" : 169,
        "Block_Mins" : 230,                
        "Ops_Week" : 3,        
        "Orig" : "AGP",
        "Dest" : "OTP",
        "Thru_Point" : "",
    },
    {    
        "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
        "Stops" : 1,
        "Seats" : 260,              
        "Block_Mins" : 260,
        "Ops_Week" : 2,  
        "Orig" : "CEK",
        "Dest" : "IKT",
        "Thru_Point" : "OVB",
    },
    {    
        "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
        "Stops" : 0,
        "Seats" : 140,
        "Block_Mins" : 60,
        "Ops_Week" : 2,        
        "Orig" : "BEK",
        "Dest" : "OTP",
        "Thru_Point" : "",
    },
    {    
        "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
        "Stops" : 0,
        "Seats" : 160,
        "Block_Mins" : 90,
        "Ops_Week" : 3,        
        "Orig" : "CEK",
        "Dest" : "OVB",
        "Thru_Point" : "",
    },
    {    
        "Mkt_Al" : "2G",        
        "Stops" : 0,
        "Seats" : 60,
        "Block_Mins" : 50,
        "Ops_Week" : 3,        
        "Orig" : "OVB",
        "Dest" : "IKT",
        "Thru_Point" : "",
    }
])
```

**Node.js app:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    async = require('async'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var volSchema = new Schema({},{ strict: false, collection: 'vols' }),    
    Vol = mongoose.model("Vol", volSchema);

mongoose.set('debug', false);

mongoose.connection.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;  
    var bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(), 
        counter = 0;

    Vol.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        var locals = {};

        docs.forEach(function(doc) {            
            locals.c1 = 0.3728 + (0.00454 * doc.Seats);         
            locals.c3 = doc.Ops_Week;

            if (doc.Stops == 1) {               
                async.series([
                    // Load doc with first leg first
                    function(callback) {
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Orig,
                            Dest: doc.Dest                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.first_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    },
                    // Load second leg doc 
                    // (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" 
                    // has been called)
                    function(callback) {                    
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Thru_Point,
                            Dest: doc.Dest                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.second_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    }
                ], function(err) { // This function gets called after the
                    // two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // Here locals will be populated with `first_leg` 
                    // and `second_leg`
                    // Just like in the previous example
                    var total_flight = locals.second_leg + locals.first_leg;                    
                    locals.c2 = 0.03;
                    locals.c4 = Math.pow((doc.Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);                    

                }); 
            } else {
                locals.c2 = 1;
                locals.c4 = 1;
            }

            counter++;
            console.log(locals);
            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({ 
                "$set": { 
                    "Qsi": (locals.c1 * locals.c2 * locals.c3 * locals.c4) 
                } 
            });

            if (counter % 500 == 0) {
               bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {          
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();                        
                });
            } 
        });

        if (counter % 500 != 0) {
            bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err; 
                console.log(result.nModified);                
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

**Sample Output:**

```
db.vols.find()

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767e7549ebce6d574702221"),
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 169,
    "Block_Mins" : 230,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Orig" : "AGP",
    "Dest" : "OTP",
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Qsi" : 3.42018
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767e7549ebce6d574702222"),
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Stops" : 1,
    "Seats" : 260,
    "Block_Mins" : 260,
    "Ops_Week" : 2,
    "Orig" : "CEK",
    "Dest" : "IKT",
    "Thru_Point" : "OVB",
    "Qsi" : 3.1064
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767e7549ebce6d574702223"),
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 140,
    "Block_Mins" : 60,
    "Ops_Week" : 2,
    "Orig" : "BEK",
    "Dest" : "OTP",
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Qsi" : 2.0168
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767e7549ebce6d574702224"),
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 160,
    "Block_Mins" : 90,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Orig" : "CEK",
    "Dest" : "OVB",
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Qsi" : 3.2976
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5767e7549ebce6d574702225"),
    "Mkt_Al" : "2G",
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 60,
    "Block_Mins" : 50,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Orig" : "OVB",
    "Dest" : "IKT",
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Qsi" : 1.9356
}
```

Comment: Thank you much much Chridam, i got an error here : `bulkUpdateOps.push({` : `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'push'`

Comment: Now I have this again ...

           `if (err) throw err; 
                                   ^
MongoError: operations must be an array of documents`

Comment: I tried it, and I got  

              `locals.second_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Block_Mins' of null`

Comment: Then it means a document hasn't been found that matches the query. I seriously think you can take this from here, do some null checks etc. The example I provided above only serves to demonstrate the concepts, not substitute for production code. It's now up to you to refactor or refine the code to suit your core needs. I think I've done enough to push you in the right direction. You need to understand the concepts here not just copy and paste the code you are given.

Comment: Thank you so muck @chridam you were so helpful and rigorous

Comment: Just one more thing Chief, I fixed the error by making a condition, and now after many iterations, i get an error just like this, I think that it belongs to the lack of memory, `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Abandon (core dumped)` Do you have any idea how to fix it and thank you !

Comment: Hii again Chief, I verified the calculation manually, and i was disappointed, both flights with stops or not, take the same value, like if the condition `if (doc.Stops == 1) {` was not there  ....

Comment: `c2` and `c4` take always value `1` ... :s

Comment: I think that I should work with async foreach, because here, with async series, like if the program wait all first legs, then he calculates the second legs, .... also for bulkinsert, I that, it should wait for these all tasks  ... ?

Comment: @JeanDupont You might be right, give that a go and please create a new question should you encounter any further hurdles.

Comment: Hiii again Chief, I think I'm lost, I didn't find the appropriate solution with async ...  Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the `Stops == 1` case, you are making an async call which will not set the value of `c4` before you use it to calculate `qsi`. The relevant block is here:

```
  if (doc.Stops == 1) {
    // do some stuff
    MyModel.find({/* some query */}).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
      // SITE A: this function will not be called for a few milliseconds
      // do some more stuff
      c4 = Math.pow((Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);
      qsi = c1 * c2 * c3 * c4;
    }); // the end of MyModel.find..
  } // end if
  else {
    c4 = 1;
  }

  qsi = c1 * c2 * c3 * c4; // SITE B: this will be called before SITE A, and qsi will be NaN since c4 is not initialized
  bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({
    "$set" : { "Qsi" : qsi } // qsi here will be from SITE B, and SITE A still hasn't been reached yet
  });
```

A rough fix would be to do something like

```
  function setQsi(qsi) {
    bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({
      "$set" : { "Qsi" : qsi }
    });
  }

  if (doc.Stops == 1) {
    // do some stuff
    MyModel.find({/* some query */}).lean().exec(function(err, docs) {
      // do some more stuff
      c4 = Math.pow((Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);
      setQsi(c1 * c2 * c3 * c4);
    }); // the end of MyModel.find..
  } // end if
  else {
    c4 = 1;
    setQsi(c1 * c2 * c3 * c4);
  }
```

For more complicated async patterns, you should look into using [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

Comment: where should I place this code : " function setQsi(qsi) { ... " ?

Comment: I intended for it to be right before the `if (doc.Stops == 1)`. But I didn't notice that you also have things like executing the bulk update ops later that will also have concurrency issues, so that might be part of the problem. For example, it could be that you didn't reset the `Qsi` values in your database, so some of the old `NaN`s didn't get overwritten due to the bulk update issues. I'll try to edit my answer accordingly later, but meanwhile do you at least understand the problem?

Comment: yes I think so, I don't know if there is another way to make things work, map reduce or somerthing oher ...

Comment: I don't know if someone can fix it or just think differently about the solution in my mongodb-query ...