# Node.js Module async.series not working properly

Tags: asynchronous, mongodb-query, async.js

I'm working on MongoDB 2.6.9 and NodeJs 0.10.37 and I have a collection vols which means flights.

According to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791777/calculate-a-score-from-an-existing-fields-with-conditions/37923637?noredirect=1#comment63520526_37923637), I have a large collection `vols` with documents like these samples :

```
> db.vols.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5717a5d4578f3f2556f300f2"),
    "Orig" : "PTH",
    "Dest" : "GMP",
    "Flight" : 126,
    "Stops" : 0,
    "Seats" : 169,
    "Ops_Week" : 3,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-14",
    "Mkt_Al" : "XX",
    "Dep_Time" : 1110,
    "Thru_Point" : "",
    "Arr_Time" : 1600,
    "Block_Mins" : 230

}
```

The next document, refers to a flight with stop.

```
> db.vols.findOne({Stops:1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5717a5d4578f3f2556f301c5"),
    "Orig" : "CIM",
    "Dest" : "LKR",
    "Flight" : 7756,
    "Stops" : 1,
    "Seats" : 70,
    "Ops_Week" : 2,
    "Eff_Date" : "2016-04-11",
    "Mkt_Al" : "YY",
    "Dep_Time" : 1655,
    "Thru_Point" : "BHU",
    "Arr_Time" : 140,
    "Block_Mins" : 345
}
```

And I have to calculate a score `for each document` with this formula and insert it into the document as a new field :

[image]

I Have tried this algorithm, using the `'async'` module with `series` method but I didn't get my desirable result ...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    express = require('express'),
    async = require('async'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var volSchema = new Schema({},{ strict: false, collection: 'vols' }),    
    Vol = mongoose.model("Vol", volSchema);

mongoose.set('debug', false);

mongoose.connection.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;  
    var bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(), 
        counter = 0;

    Vol.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        var locals = {};

        docs.forEach(function(doc) {            
            locals.c1 = 0.3728 + (0.00454 * doc.Seats);         
            locals.c3 = doc.Ops_Week;

            if (doc.Stops == 1) {               
                async.series([
                    // Load doc with first leg first
                    function(callback) {
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Orig,
                            Dest: doc.Thru_Point                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.first_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    },
                    // Load second leg doc 
                    // (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" 
                    // has been called)
                    function(callback) {                    
                        Vol.findOne({ 
                            Mkt_Al: doc.Mkt_Al,
                            Orig: doc.Thru_Point,
                            Dest: doc.Dest                          
                        }).lean().exec(function (err, flight) {
                            if (err) return callback(err);
                            locals.second_leg = flight.Block_Mins;
                            callback();
                        });
                    }
                ], function(err) { // This function gets called after the
                    // two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // Here locals will be populated with `first_leg` 
                    // and `second_leg`
                    // Just like in the previous example
                    var total_flight = locals.second_leg + locals.first_leg;                    
                    locals.c2 = 0.03;
                    locals.c4 = Math.pow((doc.Block_Mins / total_flight), -0.675);                    

                }); 
            } else {
                locals.c2 = 1;
                locals.c4 = 1;
            }

            counter++;
            console.log(locals);
            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id" : doc._id }).updateOne({ 
                "$set": { 
                    "Qsi": (locals.c1 * locals.c2 * locals.c3 * locals.c4) 
                } 
            });

            if (counter % 500 == 0) {
               bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {          
                    if (err) throw err; 
                    bulkUpdateOps = Vol.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();                        
                });
            } 
        });

        if (counter % 500 != 0) {
            bulkUpdateOps.execute(function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err; 
                console.log(result.nModified);                
            });
        }   
    });
});
```

At the end I find myself with a result that is the same in both cases, flight with **stop** or **not**.

I think that the secend task wich calculate second legs, waits until the calculation of all first_legs, instead of after each first_leg.

Also the insertion of the score must wait until the end of calculating the score for each document, I think `bulkinsert` should take place after other calculations.

Now I don't know if I should work with **async.series** or **async.foreach** or **async.parralel** or combinate them ...

Please who can help to achieve the above ...

Comment: Please who can help ?

Comment: no one to help here ?